# Calling data-onsucess for Google sign in in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-signin

I am trying to create a sign in functionality using the using [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) The button appears in my application, The login process completes successfully but the onSignIn(googleUser) method is never called.
I think i have to bind the button somehow in my component file and attach the callback but have not yet found out on how to do this using Angular 5.

How do i trigger the callback on (data-onsuccess) when login completes and pass the retrieved user to onSignIn(googleUser) in Register.component.ts?

### register.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RegisterService} from './register.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  constructor(private registerService: RegisterService) {

  }

  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    this.registerService.googleSignIn(googleUser);
  }
}
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="obfuscated for Stack Overflow">
  <title>Thee</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

### register.component.html

```
<div class="g-signin2" (data-onsuccess)="onSignIn()"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the whole project or stack blitz? There's not enough info to help you.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your compnent.ts file

```
declare const gapi: any;
ngOnInit() {
this.googleInit();}
public auth2: any;


public googleInit() {
let that = this;
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
  that.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  });
  that.onSignIn(that.element.nativeElement.firstChild);
}); }
onSignIn(element) {
console.log('element is now ', element);

this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
  function (googleUser) {

var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
const desc = {
  'ID: ' : profile.getId(),
  'Name: ' : profile.getName(),
  // 'Image URL: ' : profile.getImageUrl(),
  'Email: ' : profile.getEmail()
}
alert(JSON.stringify(desc));
// console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
console.log(profile)
console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.})};}
```